# Find network interface by IP address - Linux/Bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm wondering how I can query by IP address using sed, and it will show which interface name that is using it.

For example..

```
ipconfig -a | grep 10.0.0.10
```

I would expect it to come back with ETH0

Comment: For a start it's `ifconfig`, `ipconfig` is a DOS command (I'm guessing that was a typo though). So what is the output of `ifconfig -a` on its own then? Is there a NIC on your system with an IP of `10.0.0.10` listed?

Comment: Note on `systemd` init OS's `ipconfig` may not be installed, instead the `ip` command is used (`ip addr` specifically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this comand :

```
ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr:10.0.0.10" | awk '$1!="inet" && $1!="--" {print $1}'
```

Hope this help !

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help if the OP couldn't find what they were after using plain old `grep 10.0.0.10` then adding to the string to find still won't find it.

Comment: can you explain more? what is `OP` , and you'd to print out ethernet_name  if it's match with given ip address, right ?

Comment: OP = original poster, and btw Thanh, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: No, anything with `grep x | awk '{ y }'` is usually better written `awk '/x/ { y }'` - this is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Although it appends a newline character to the end though? Why is that?

Answer (score 6):

```
ifconfig | grep -B1 10.0.0.10 | grep -o "^\w*"
```

Comment: Good solution without awk

Comment: Doesn't work with multiple IPs in a single network card.

Answer (score 2):

```
ip -br -4 a sh | grep 10.0.0.10 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want sed specific solution you may try this. Its little hard to digest how it works , but finally this combination works.

```
 ifconfig | sed -n '/addr:10.0.0.10/{g;H;p};H;x' | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you want to take it as an argument via script use "$1" or so instead if 10.0.0.10.

Sed manual for reference : http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#tail